# How to open popups automatically after certain time (without blocking)

Tags: javascript, php, html, firefox, popup

I am making a web page, in which I have to open a popup window from an buton after 8 seconds(8000 ms).
I want to put some delay(8 seconds) before a popup open automatically.

**my problem is that mozilla firefox block my popup**

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function call()
        {
            popup = window.open('http://www.google.co.in');         
                 }   
        function caller()
        {
            setInterval(call, 8000);
        }
       </script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="button" onclick="caller();">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way around a browser's popup blocking/displaying architecture. All you can do is call the JS method. What happens then is outside the HTML/JS purview.

Javascript popups are really kind of out of fashion on the web, because of the blockers. They're annoying, their behavior depending on device is unpredictable, and generally, users hate them. Consider another approach.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the function `setTimeout(functionName , delay)` instead of setInterval. setInterval will popup a new window every 8 seconds while setTimeout will only do it once.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function call()
        {
            popup = window.open('http://www.google.co.in');         
        }

        setTimeout(call, 8000);

     </script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="button" onclick="caller();">
</body>
</html>
```

And I'm agree, look for an another way to do what you want. Popups are often a inconvenience for users, especially for partially-sighted person.

By default many web browser block automatic popup. They only alow popup for direct action like in an onClick envent.